# xrandr | grep " connected " give me more than one line but IFS=$'\n' read can't break it

Tags: linux, shell, grep, string

I have something like this:

```
declare -a DISPLAYS
AUXILIAR="$(xrandr | grep " connected ")"
IFS=$'\n' read -ra DISPLAYS <<< "$AUXILIAR"
```

Why it isn't detecting line breaks if

```
echo "$AUXILIAR"
```

Print more than one line?

**UPDATE**

This work inded:

```
AUXILIAR="$(xrandr | grep " connected " | tr '\n' '%')"
IFS='%' read -ra DISPLAYS <<< $(echo $AUXILIAR)
```

I still want to know why it did not split in break lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `read` will only read only *one line at a time*.  For example, here we provide *three* lines of input and, as you can see, `read` only reads the first line:

```
$ IFS=$'\n' read -ra displays <<< $'a\nb\nc\n'; declare -p displays
declare -a displays='([0]="a")'
```

The `-d` option can be used to change this behavior.  For example:

```
$ IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra displays <<< $'a\nb\nc\n'; declare -p displays
declare -a displays='([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c")
```

Here, `-d ''` was used.  This tells `read` to read until it finds a NUL character.  Since there can never be a NUL character in a bash string, this causes it to read all the input that we supply with the here-string.

#### Using %

```
$ IFS=% read -ra displays <<< 'a%b%c'; declare -p displays
declare -a displays='([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c")'
```

Using `%` works because `read` continues reading past `%`.  By default, it only stops for newline characters.

#### Other

It is considered best practices to use lower or mixed-case names for your variables.  The system uses upper-case names and you don't want to accidentally overwrite one of them.  For example, `DISPLAY` is a system variable and many unpleasant problems could occur if it was overwritten.

Comment: Thanks, including the appointment about variable names, didn't know about it as shell is somewhat new to me. :)